# Detect new unread message of whatsapp selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am developing a bot that should check the number of received and unread messages on the WhatsApp web and open that unread message whose message is a photo and download that photo.

I am using selenium and python also getting the 1st unread message but unable to open rest of the unread message

```
chrome = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
chrome.get("https://web.whatsapp.com")    
chrome.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="pane-side"]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/span[1]/div').text
```

This code is giving the 1st unread message so I want to get the list of all unread messages having a photo and download that photo and get a dictionary at the end for example

```
{
'sender':'photo path',
'amad':'c:/path/img.png',
'jake':'c:/path/image2.png'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

after long research and taking different solutions like pywhatkit, alright etc i came to the conclusion as below

```
a=[]
y= chrome.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="pane-side"]/div/div/div').get_attribute("aria-rowcount")
for i in range(1,int(y)+1):
a.append(chrome.find_element_by_css_selector('._3uIPm').find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"pane-side\"]/div/div/div/div["+str(i)+"]"))
```

This gives us the list like this

```
['contact name/number','time posted','last message either photo, video,audio or a text message', '(number of unread messages of that contact)']
```

**get unread message we can use**

```
final_unread=[]
for i in b:
    if i[-1].isnumeric():
        final_unread.append(i)
print(final_unread)
```

**Chat with last Message a photo**

```
chat_with_photos=[]
j=0
for i in b:
    if i[-1]=='Photo' or i[-2]=='Photo':
        i.append(a[j])
        print(i)
        chat_with_photos.append(i)
    j=j+1
```

here `a` is the list with selenium objects

**Scrap all photos we can use**

```
for i in chat_with_photos:
    contact_name=i[0]
    try:
        contact=chrome.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@title=\""+contact_name+"\"]")
    except:
        print('Searching using search box')
        search_box_xpath = '//div[@class="_2S1VP copyable-text selectable-text"][@contenteditable="true"][@data-tab="3"]'
        search_box= WebDriverWait(chrome,50).until(lambda chrome: chrome.find_element_by_xpath(search_box_xpath))
        search_box.click()
        search_box.send_keys(contact_name)
        contact= chrome.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@title=\"'+contact_name+'\"]')
    contact.click()
    time.sleep(2)
    image_xpath='//img[@class="jciay5ix tvf2evcx oq44ahr5 lb5m6g5c"]'
    image_src=chrome.find_element_by_xpath(image_xpath).get_attribute('src')
    print(image_src)
    time.sleep(2)
    result = chrome.execute_async_script("""
                        var uri = arguments[0];
                        var callback = arguments[1];
                        var toBase64 = function(buffer){for(var r,n=new Uint8Array(buffer),t=n.length,a=new Uint8Array(4*Math.ceil(t/3)),i=new Uint8Array(64),o=0,c=0;64>c;++c)i[c]="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/".charCodeAt(c);for(c=0;t-t%3>c;c+=3,o+=4)r=n[c]<<16|n[c+1]<<8|n[c+2],a[o]=i[r>>18],a[o+1]=i[r>>12&63],a[o+2]=i[r>>6&63],a[o+3]=i[63&r];return t%3===1?(r=n[t-1],a[o]=i[r>>2],a[o+1]=i[r<<4&63],a[o+2]=61,a[o+3]=61):t%3===2&&(r=(n[t-2]<<8)+n[t-1],a[o]=i[r>>10],a[o+1]=i[r>>4&63],a[o+2]=i[r<<2&63],a[o+3]=61),new TextDecoder("ascii").decode(a)};
                        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                        xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
                        xhr.onload = function(){ callback(toBase64(xhr.response)) };
                        xhr.onerror = function(){ callback(xhr.status) };
                        xhr.open('GET', uri);
                        xhr.send();
                        """, image_src)
    time.sleep(2)
    if type(result) == int :
        raise Exception("Request failed with status %s" % result)
    final_image = base64.b64decode(result)
    filename = 'images/'+contact_name+'.jpg'
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(final_image)
        print("Saving "+filename+", Go To The Next Image")
    time.sleep(2)
    print(image_src)
```

all photos will be downloaded in a folder named `images`